# grails 2.3 spring security without sessions

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.3

I am using grails 2.3 and spring security plugin 1.2.7.3 (no issues in upgrading to 2.0 once released, and if that could solve my prob). I am NOT using hibernate plugin. And i want a sessionless authentication on the server side. Need the configurations in Config.groovy / any custom classes that needs to be implemented.

Comment: did you try Remember Me authentication?

Comment: is it the remember me in the login box? how does it help the server to be sessionless?

Comment: RememberMe store user details in Cookie, not Session